Memory Issue with Ray in Cluster Environment
I'm new to using Ray, and I've set up a workflow to read and process several .csv files using Pandas. Here's a snippet of my setup:
with on_ray(
    num_cpus=6,
    object_store_memory=10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
    _temp_dir="../../ray",
    include_dashboard=True,
    ignore_reinit_error=True,
    _plasma_directory="../../ray"
):

    for data_type in DATA_TYPES:
        print(f"Processing data type: {data_type}")
        result_ids = [_process.remote(data_type, path_chunk) for path_chunk in generator_paths_dataset(data_type, 8)]
        
        while result_ids:
            done_ids, result_ids = ray.wait(result_ids, num_returns=2)
            for done_id in done_ids:
                try:
                    result = ray.get(done_id)
                    jobs = accumulate_results(jobs, result)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error retrieving result for ID {done_id}: {e}")
                del result
                gc.collect()

            print(f"Processed IDs: {done_ids}")
            print(f"Remaining IDs: {len(result_ids)}")

    dump(jobs, os.path.join(PATH_SENSOR, 'proc.pkl'))
    print("Duration =", time.time() - start)
    del jobs
    gc.collect()

I have 70 .csv files, processed in chunks of 8, and then perform calculations on these chunks. The setup is running on a local machine with 8 CPUs and 32GB of RAM, and the entire process takes approximately 12 minutes. I receive a warning about memory usage reaching the 32GB limit during the last chunk, but the process completes successfully.
However, when I run the same configuration in a cluster with 6 CPUs and 70GB of RAM, I encounter the following error:
=>> PBS: job killed: vmem 133719207936 exceeded limit 75161927680. It ask for ~ 110GB of memory and kill the process.
The job requests around 110GB of memory, causing it to be terminated. I'm unsure how to debug this issue or identify the root cause. I've read about potential memory leakage problems in Ray, but I haven't found clear guidance.
Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
